# Пишу программу для вычисления определённых интегралов

Tags: java, математика

Пишу программу для вычисления определённых интегралов. У меня получилось её написать при уже заранее введённом интеграле, но я не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы тот же самый интеграл можно было вводить с клавиатуры (строку "1/lnx")

Код для вычисления интеграла 1/lnx:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Решаем определённый интеграл интегра 1/lnx, от a до b");

        double n = 5;
        System.out.println("Введите нижний предел");
        double a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Введите верихний предел");
        double b = scanner.nextInt();
        double step = 2;
        double sum = 1/(Math.log(step));
        double res;
        double h = (b-a)/n;
        for (int i = 1;i<5;i++){
            step = step + h;
            sum = sum + 1/(Math.log(step));

        }
        res = h*sum;
        System.out.println(res);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Для начала стоит вынести функцию в отдельную функцию.

Comment: А разбор символьного выражения это задачка на пару порядков сложнее, чем ваша и наверняка именно поэтому вас и не просят её делать. Кстати ваше 1/lnx вообще вряд ли распарсится. Хотя бы 1/ln(x)

Comment: Для вычисления выражения по строке, воспользуйтесь ScriptEngine https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html пример: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java